# JQuery Mobile: .val() not working

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Greetings,

I have the following jQuery Mobile code:

```
<div data-role="content">
  A confirmation code has been sent to your mobile phone via SMS
  <br><br>
  To proceed, please enter the 3-digit confirmation code below:
  <br>
  <input id="verifySMS_code" type="text"  /><br>
  <a id="verifySMS_submit" href="#" data-role="button">Submit</a>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#verifySMS_submit").live("click",function() {
    alert('hi');
    var code=$('input#verifySMS_code').val();
    alert(code);
  });
});
```

'hi' appears in the first alert box, however '' appears in the second alert box - i.e. totally blank!!!

I've tried document.getElementById('verifySMS_code') too to no avail.

I've even tried jquery mobile 1.0a3pre

This is a really serious problem for me and I've no idea how to fix it.

I hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you type something into the input box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install firebug
2. Test it with

`<input id="verifySMS_code" type="text" value="someoldvalue" />`

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#verifySMS_submit").bind("submit",function() {
    console.log($('#verifySMS_code'));
    var code=$('#verifySMS_code').val();
    console.log(code);
  });
});
```

This is why:

- the `value=` in the input will show
  if it's a problem with getting the
  value or with putting what you enter
  into the input element (jquery mobile
  builds something on the input)
- you will not generate new submit buttons matching "#verifySMS_submit"
  so you don't need `live()` there
- try it with click and with submit. I suppose jquery mobile is putting
  text from the input control to the
  input itself at some certain moments
  like `blur` event on the input, so it
  happens when you click something
  else, not before that
- `console.log($('input#verifySMS_code'));`
  will pop up your element in console.
  if empty array pops up - there was no
  such element and it's a selector
  problem.

---

Test for inputs with duplicated IDs.

This shows all ids: `$('input').each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('id'));});`
Run it in firebug and it will also point to DOM so you can click and find them in HTML tab.

Comment: Hey, many thanks for your reply. It's really been helpful sofar. I took your advice of setting value="someoldvalue". This value comes up on console.log. When I remove the value="someoldvalue" and do a console.log on $('#verifySMS_code').val(), it just returns an empty string... I'm totally stuck. Wasted about 2 days sofar! I think jQuery Mobile is doing something to the DOM and I can't figure it out... Tried this in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: jquery mobile builds a component over the input. I'm a bit busy now so I can't reproduce it. I'll look into it if you publish the thing somewhere and post a link in a comment.

Comment: Got it. Somehow there are two identical pages with two inputs with the same ID. jQuery requires unique ids and it finds only one element by id - the first from top. Run `$('input').each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('id'));});` in firebug and see for yourself.

Comment: PS. The html looks a bit messy - there's a lot of script tags between some pages. Where did that come from? Are you using jqm default loading methods or hacking it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Somehow, it looks like JQuery Mobile doesn't handle well the syntax `("#someId")`

Instead, doing `("input[id=verifySMS_code]").val()` should help

Answer (score 2):

If You have get duplicate id's (after page loading or using `changePage()` etc.) then try accessing the children of the active page object ...
Ex.

```
var myval = $('form#src #search').val(); // returns incorrect (:first) value of the element
```

replace with

```
var myval = $.mobile.activePage.find('form#src #search').val();
```

Anyway, worked form me:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a particular page. Then I realized I had some code that was calling a `changePage()` to the same page, thereby duplicating the dom element and its id.